# Not able to generate migrations in docker django application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run migrations in the Django application that is using docker but the changes are not reflecting. I had no issue with the initial migrations but after that, if I make any changes to my models that are not reflected in the migrations and it keeps generating initial migrations.

I am not able to find any migration file too maybe that is causing this problem but I am not able to find any solution.

I am using amazon RDS as database and application is also hosted on AWS and I am using this command for migrations.

**docker-compose -f production.yml run django python manage.py makemigrations app_name**

Comment: try `docker-compose -f production.yml "/bin/bash -l  -c 'django python manage.py makemigrations app_name'"`

Comment: I am getting this error. No such command: /bin/bash _l _c 'django python manage.py makemigrations app_name . Aso tried docker-compose -f production.yml run "/bin/bash -l -c 'django python manage.py makemigrations app_name'".